# Concatenate two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have written this code to append two numpy arrays:

```
td_XN = searchNegative(X,y,10)
td_XP = searchPosotive(X,y,10)
print(np.array(td_XN).shape, np.array(td_XP).shape)
print(type(td_XN), type(td_XP))
td_X = np.concatenate(td_XP, td_XN)
td_y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
print(td_X.shape, len(td_y))
```

However, it produces this error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

On this line:

```
td_X = np.concatenate(td_XP, td_XN)
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of td_XN and td_XP?

Comment: You need `td_X = np.vstack([td_XP, td_XN])`, The two elements need to wrapped in an itterable.

Comment: @Miriam (10, 2544) (10, 2544)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate side by side (that is, create an array of 10 -by- 2544*2): you can do

```
td_X = np.concatenate([td_XP, td_XN],axis=1)
```

For example

```
td_X = np.concatenate([[[1,2,3,7],[4,5,6,8]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]],axis=1)
```

gives

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6]])
```

On the other hand, if you want to add `td_XN` below `td_XP` you can do

```
td_X = np.concatenate([td_XP, td_XN],axis=0)
```

For example,

```
td_X = np.concatenate([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,7],[4,5,8]]],axis=0)
```

gives

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 7],
       [4, 5, 8]])
```